# Pandas - Access a value in Column B based on a value in Column A

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

So I have a small set of data, `TFR.csv` taking the form:

```
Year     State1     State2     State3
1993       3          4           5
1994       6          2           1.4
...
```

I am supposed to determine when State 2's value is at its lowest (1994), and extract whatever value State 3 has in that year (1.4).

To do this, I've written a short filter:

```
State1Min = min(TFR['State1']) #Determine the minimum value for State1

filt = (TFR['State1']==State1Min) #Filter to select the row where the value exists

TFR[filt]['State3'] #Apply this filter to the original table, and return the value in the State3 column.
```

It returns the right value I'm looking for, but also the row number at the front:

```
2     1.4
Name: NT, dtype: float64
```

I need to print this value of 1.4, so I'm trying to find a way to extract it out of this output.

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: @Chris answer below is best, but you could also just add....TFR[filt]['State3'].values[0]

Comment: @run-out Thank you so much, that did it! Chris' answer works too, but I'm not at that level yet where I've come across those functions as I'm just a beginner at this point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.set_index` and `idxmin`:

```
df = df.set_index('Year')
df.loc[df['State2'].idxmin(), 'State3']
```

Output:

```
1.4
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I ended up using a method listed above in a comment since its more my speed as I'm just a beginner, but you've given me pointers on how to proceed with learning the language.